# Help with Calculated Column conditional formula with OR

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to categorize a SharePoint list of projects into colored approval tracks based on project type using a calculated column. So, depending on the choice from the Project Type column, the calculated column displays a certain color. I am using nested IF( and OR( operators in my formula, but am getting the syntax error message. Can anyone see what's wrong with my formula?

```
IF(OR([Project Type]="WD",[Project Type]="TAB",[Project Type]="Guide"),"Blue",IF(OR([Project Type]="DP",[Project Type]="Plan",[Project Type]="Report",[Project Type]="Rule",[Project Type]="Waiver"),"Red",IF(OR([Project Type]="BP",[Project Type]="Federal Review"),"Green"),IF(OR([Project Type]="Leg. Analysis",[Project Type]="Correspondence"),"Grey","Gold"))))
```

Desired outcome:

- Project Type: WD, TAB, or Guide = Approval Track: Blue
- Project Type: DP, Plan, Report, Rule, or Waiver = Approval Track: Red
- Project Type: BP or Federal Review = Approval Track: Green
- Project Type: Leg. Analysis or Correspondence = Approval Track: Grey
- All other Project Types = Approval Track: Gold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was one extra `)` after `"Green"` in your formula. So, try using this formula like this:

```
IF(
    OR([Project Type]="WD",[Project Type]="TAB",[Project Type]="Guide"),
    "Blue",
    IF(
        OR([Project Type]="DP",[Project Type]="Plan",[Project Type]="Report",[Project Type]="Rule",[Project Type]="Waiver"),
        "Red",
        IF(
            OR([Project Type]="BP",[Project Type]="Federal Review"),
            "Green",
            IF(
                OR([Project Type]="Leg. Analysis",[Project Type]="Correspondence"),
                "Grey",
                "Gold"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: Yes, thank you! I stared for hours and couldn't find that extra ). Appreciate your help!